# Split one column into three different ones

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Clusters   Names                    
Cluster17  bloc_7638_13482_15158
Cluster18  YP_1889.1_1254_16819_18840
Cluster19  bloc_15158_10862_11248
Cluster20  IDBE_DJD_A_20193_2267_2773
Cluster20  HDHDHD.1_21671_1013_1522
```

And I would like to split the `Names` columns into 3 columns like this:

```
Clusters   COL1             COL2   COL3                    
Cluster17  bloc_7638        13482  15158
Cluster18  YP_1889.1_1254   16819  18840
Cluster19  bloc_15158       10862  11248
Cluster20  IDBE_DJD_A_20193 2267   2773
Cluster20  HDHDHD.1_21671   1013   1522
```

Where

- COL3 has all the last numbers of Name
- COL2 has all the pre-last numbers of Name
- COL1 has all the rest

Here is the dataframe in dict format if it helps:

```
{'Clusters': {0: 'Cluster17', 1: 'Cluster18', 2: 'Cluster19', 3: 'Cluster20', 4: 'Cluster20'}, 'Names': {0: 'bloc_7638_13482_15158', 1: 'YP_1889.1_1254_16819_18840', 2: 'bloc_15158_10862_11248', 3: 'IDBE_DJD_A_20193_2267_2773', 4: 'HDHDHD.1_21671_1013_1522'}}
```

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.str.rsplit`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) to split by `_`, starting from the right, and only split twice:

```
df[['COL1', 'COL2', 'COL3']] = df['Names'].str.rsplit('_', n=2, expand=True)
df = df.drop('Names', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    Clusters              COL1   COL2   COL3
0  Cluster17         bloc_7638  13482  15158
1  Cluster18    YP_1889.1_1254  16819  18840
2  Cluster19        bloc_15158  10862  11248
3  Cluster20  IDBE_DJD_A_20193   2267   2773
4  Cluster20    HDHDHD.1_21671   1013   1522
```